# Retrieve applied Gradle plugin keys

Tags: gradle, plugins, groovy

There is `PluginRegistry` to lookup Plugin by its key, i.e. by loading its directly by the file name. But how can we retrieve applied Gradle plugin keys?

Please suggest simpler solution than traversing the *.jar* files.

Comment: To be clear you want to know how to find the `id` for the plugins during the build?  Like `plugin apply: 'blah'` you want to know the blah?

Comment: Yes, do you know any mechanism to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this information is not kept by Gradle.  We can dump a few items to confirm this `project.plugins`, `project.pluginManager`, `gradle.plugins` and `gradle.pluginManager`.  While the `id`'s are not kept we can still determine the plugins installed by their class.

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = 'com.jbirdvegas.q41287036'
version = '0.1'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

println "Plugins: ${project.plugins.size()}"
project.plugins.each {
    println it.getClass().getCanonicalName()
}

println "\nproject.plugins dump: \n${project.plugins.dump()}"
println "\nproject.pluginManager dump: \n${project.pluginManager.dump()}"

task nothing {}

println "\n\ngradle.plugins dump: \n${gradle.plugins.dump()}"
println "\n\ngradle.pluginManager dump: \n${gradle.pluginManager.dump()}"
```

Then when we run we can see the class for each applied plugin however `id` is not kept.

```
$ ./gradlew -b build_simple.gradle -q nothing
Plugins: 12
com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin
org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin
org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin
org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin
org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin

project.plugins dump: 
<org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer@45947ad4 pluginRegistry=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry@78154b46 pluginManager=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated@1eb1cc4a type=interface org.gradle.api.Plugin eventRegister=org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionEventRegister@7530d0a2 store=[com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin@523efb4c, org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin@509441c8, org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin@7731a4ac, org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin@6f9eb0ab, org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin@7c2b8596, org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin@13fddaba, org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin@335afa66, org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin@4aad9daf, org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin@39ac90d9, org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin@c55ff20, org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin@7f6bbaa3, org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin@32cfecd3] mutateActions=[]>

project.pluginManager dump: 
<org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated@1eb1cc4a __dyn_obj__=null __meta_class__=groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@42a21d1d[class org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated] instantiator=org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator@3d4ec275 applicator=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator@4f48cb44 pluginRegistry=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry@78154b46 pluginContainer=[com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin@523efb4c, org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin@509441c8, org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin@7731a4ac, org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin@6f9eb0ab, org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin@7c2b8596, org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin@13fddaba, org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin@335afa66, org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin@4aad9daf, org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin@39ac90d9, org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin@c55ff20, org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin@7f6bbaa3, org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin@32cfecd3] plugins=[class org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@557e4a5, class org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@57cf4be7, class com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@1cd97601, class org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@15c28c35, class org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@2f8a30e4, class org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@237d681, class org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@5589c1b8, class org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@542b5c18, class org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@2a585b69, class org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@1667137d, class org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@d789408, class org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin:org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$RegistryAwarePluginImplementation@33dd223] instances=[class org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin:org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin@13fddaba, class org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin:org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin@4aad9daf, class com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin:com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanPlugin@523efb4c, class org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin:org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin@7731a4ac, class org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin@39ac90d9, class org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin:org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin@335afa66, class org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin@509441c8, class org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin@c55ff20, class org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin@6f9eb0ab, class org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin@7c2b8596, class org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin@7f6bbaa3, class org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin:org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin@32cfecd3] idMappings=[:]>


gradle.plugins dump: 
<org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer@61d42bc5 pluginRegistry=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry@38ca4273 pluginManager=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated@5fef5ff0 type=interface org.gradle.api.Plugin eventRegister=org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionEventRegister@79b9180f store=[] mutateActions=[]>


gradle.pluginManager dump: 
<org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated@5fef5ff0 __dyn_obj__=null __meta_class__=groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@42a21d1d[class org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated] instantiator=org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator@53c09a79 applicator=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator@76f54f2e pluginRegistry=org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry@38ca4273 pluginContainer=[] plugins=[:] instances=[:] idMappings=[:]>
```